# Combustion Temperature Calculation Using C_p and Heat of Formation

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I am simulating the combustion temperature for various compositions of syngas and finding the product temperature. Part one is varying the ratio of CO and H2 from 3:1 to 1:3 in the syngas, burning it with air (21/79 O2/N2), and finding the temperature/composition. Part two is fixing the composition of the syngas and increasing the amount of N2 introduced into the system and again finding the temperature and composition. Lastly, everything is fixed but there is heat loss through the system (~1000 J / mol). Temperature and composition is found. As you can tell, the code between all three parts would be similar. I am stuck on on part that I think is the last step. I have already solved the system of equations described below using sypmy fsolve(). Then I need to calculate the temperature by iterating.

The general equation for the chemical reaction is as follows:

aCO + bH2 + c*(O2 + 79/21 * N2) + dN2 = eCO + fH2 + gO2 + hN2 + jCO2 + kH2O + lNO

From conservation of species:

Carbon: a = e + j

Oxygen: a + 2c = e + 2g + 2*j + k + l

Hydrogen: 2b = 2f + 2*k

Nitrogen: 2*(79/21)c + 2d = 2*h + l

Since there are three compounds, there are three partial pressure equilibrium values called K_p. K_p is a function of temperature and from empirical data is a known constant.

K_p_NO = (X_NO * P) / (sqrt(X_N2*P)*sqrt(X_O2 * P))

K_p_H2O = (X_H2O * P) / (sqrt(P*X_O2)X_H2P)

K_p_CO2 = (X_CO2 * P) / (sqrt(P*X_O2)X_COP)

Where X is the mole fraction. E.G. X_H2O = k/(e+f+g+h+j+k+l)

Please note that in the below code, enthalpy is denoted with a dG instead of a dH.

```python
# There are three parts to this project is split into three parts.
# The First is to calculate the flame temperatures and equilibrium
# composition of syngas and air. Syngas is comprised of mainly
# CO and H2. Sometimes CO2 and CH4 are present, these are ignored.


# Importing Properties. The Specific heat and delta enthalpy of each species is input via empirical_funcs.py.
# The gases used are O2, CO2, H2O, CO, H2, N2, and NO.
# Air is assumed to be 79% Nitrogen Gas and 21% Oxygen
# Air is at 600 K, fuel is at 300 K, pressure is 5 atm.


import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import math as m
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import empirical_funcs as emp
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


# Constants
R = 8.3145  # J / mol / K
dec = 50  # decimal point precision
i = 0
p = 5
# standard heat of formation for elements is zero
h_0_f_CO = -110.541  # kJ/mol
h_0_f_CO2 = -393.546  # kJ/mol
h_0_f_H20 = 241.845  # kJ/mol
h_0_f_NO = 90.297  # kJ/mol
flag = 0
T = 1.7  # Temperature (K)/1000

# PART 1: calculate the equilibrium product composition and adiabatic flame
# temperature for a stoichiometric syngas-air flame fueled only by CO and H2.
# For CO/H2, vary composition from 75/25 to 25/75 by volume.
T_fuel = 0.3
T_air = 0.6
ratio_lower = 25
ratio_upper = 75
increment = 5
T_data = np.zeros((len(range(ratio_lower, ratio_upper, increment)), 1))  # Initialise T_Data array
co_h2_ratio = [*range(ratio_lower, ratio_upper, increment)]
i_len = len(co_h2_ratio)


def solver():
    global T, flag, i
    # aCO + bH2 + c(O2 + 79/21 N2) + dN2 -> eCO + fH2 + gO2 + hN2 + jCO2 + kH20 + lNO
    a = co_h2_ratio[i] / 100
    b = 1 - a
    c = a + b
    d = 0  # For first part

    # Starting temperature is found from mixing reactants, DBL CHECK
    n_cp_air = c * emp.get_cp('O2', T_air) + (79 / 21) * c * emp.get_cp('N2', T_air)
    n_cp_fuel = a * emp.get_cp('CO', T_fuel) + b * emp.get_cp('H2', T_fuel)
    T_reactants = (1000 * T_fuel * n_cp_fuel + 1000 * T_air * n_cp_air) / (n_cp_fuel + n_cp_air)
    T_reactants = T_reactants / 1000
    kp_NO = emp.get_kp('NO', T)
    kp_H2O = emp.get_kp('H20', T)
    kp_CO2 = emp.get_kp('CO2', T)

    # Solving the system of equations
    def equations(vars):
        e, f, g, h, j, k, l = vars
        f1 = e + j - a
        f2 = e + 2 * g + 2 * j + k + l - a - 2 * c
        f3 = f + k - b
        f4 = 2 * h + l - 2 * d - (2 * 79 / 21) * c
        f5 = kp_NO - (l / (sp.sqrt(h)*sp.sqrt(g)))
        f6 = kp_H2O - 1/(k / (f * sp.sqrt((g * p) / (e + f + g + h + j + k + l))))
        f7 = kp_CO2 - 1/(j / (e * sp.sqrt((g * p) / (e + f + g + h + j + k + l))))
        return [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7]
    e, f, g, h, j, k, l = scipy.optimize.fsolve(equations, (0.00004, 0.00004, 0.49, 3.76, 0.25, 0.75, 0.01))


    # e, f, g, h, j, k, l = sp.symbols('e, f, g, h, j, k, l')
    # f1 = e + j - a
    # f2 = e + 2 * g + 2 * j + k + l - a - 2 * c
    # f3 = f + k - b
    # f4 = 2 * h + l - 2 * d - (2 * 79 / 21) * c
    # f5 = kp_NO - (l / (c * (79 / 21) * c))
    # f6 = kp_H2O - (k / (b * sp.sqrt((c * p) / (e + f + g + h + j + k + l))))
    # f7 = kp_CO2 - (j / (a * sp.sqrt((c * p) / (e + f + g + h + j + k + l))))
    # results = sp.solvers.nsolve([f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7], [e, f, g, h, j, k, l],
    #                                 [0.0001, 0.00000001, 0.00000000001, 0.000000001, 0.0000001, 0.000000001, 0.000000001])
    #
    # e = round(results[0], dec)
    # f = round(results[1], dec)
    # g = round(results[2], dec)
    # h = round(results[3], dec)
    # j = round(results[4], dec)
    # k = round(results[5], dec)
    # l = round(results[6], dec)

    print('CO = ', e, 'H2 = ', f, 'O2 = ', g, 'N2 = ', h, 'CO2 = ', j, 'H2O = ', k, 'NO = ', l)
    print('a = ', a, 'b = ', b)

    # Reactants
    dG_CO = emp.get_dG('CO', T)
    dG_H2 = emp.get_dG('H2', T)
    dG_O2 = emp.get_dG('O2', T)
    dG_N2 = emp.get_dG('N2', T)

    # Products
    dG_CO2 = emp.get_dG('CO2', T)
    dG_H20 = emp.get_dG('H20', T)
    dG_NO = emp.get_dG('NO', T)

    # Insert equation for components below.
    # Reactants are either consumed or there is some excess/remainder meaning that the Product side is simply summed

    eq_co2 = j*(h_0_f_CO2 + dG_CO2 - emp.get_cp('CO2', T_reactants))
    eq_h2o = k*(h_0_f_H20 + dG_H20 - emp.get_cp('H20', T_reactants))
    eq_no = l*(h_0_f_NO + dG_NO - emp.get_dG('NO', T_reactants))
    eq_co = e*(h_0_f_CO + dG_CO - emp.get_dG('CO', T_reactants))
    eq_h2 = f * (dG_H2 - emp.get_dG('H2', T_reactants))
    eq_o2 = g * (dG_O2 - emp.get_dG('O2', T_reactants))
    eq_n2 = h * (dG_N2 - emp.get_dG('N2', T_reactants))
    print('CO2 = ', eq_co2, 'H2O = ', eq_h2o, 'NO = ', eq_no, 'CO = ', eq_co, 'H2 = ', eq_h2, 'O2 = ', eq_o2, 'N2 = ', eq_n2)
    f8 = eq_co2 + eq_h2o + eq_no + eq_co + eq_h2 + eq_o2 + eq_n2  # should equal zero, if not, iterate T
    print('f8: ', f8)
    print('T =', T)
    if 100 > f8 > -100:
        flag = 1
        print(T)
        T_data[i] = T
        T = 1.7
        i = i + 1
        print('i = ', i)
        flag = 0

        if i == i_len:
            mpl.plot(range(ratio_lower, ratio_upper, increment), T_data)
            mpl.show()
            exit()
        solver()
    else:
        if f8 > 0:
            T = T - 0.02
        else:
            T = T + 0.02
        solver()


solver()
```

The way I am solving for temperature is by (assuming adiabatic) that

0 = n_products(h_product_formation + cp_product * dT) - n_reactants(h_reactants_formation + cp_reactant * dT)

dT being (T(im trying to find) - T_mixing (I think) The air and fuel are 600 and 300 K respectively. Since I have to iterate to find T, I start with a guess and continue until the above equation is satisfied. However, I am not getting results that align with what gasEq gives me. IS THE ABOVE EQUATION CORRECT? If so, how is it being implemented incorrectly?

Example result:
[image: Example Result; Wrong, supposed to be from roughly 1700 to 1850 K]

Comment: Welcome to the site, but please try to condense and make this question clearer. As it stands it's rather lengthy and contains information likely not relevant to the question(s) at hand.

Comment: You may find useful these links for text formatting ( not to be applied to titles ):
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [text + formula formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  

and [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See [Carbon Dioxide - Specific Heat of Gas vs. Temperature](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/carbon-dioxide-d_974.html) and the same for water: [Water Vapor - Specific Heat](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-vapor-d_979.html)

Comment: Do you have a reference for your chemical equation for the composition of syngas?